PostgreSQL: return json as a list
I have mixed types of values in the columns but all of them are json object:
one field stored as text in column_a:
{'field0': 'value0'}

another field as json (list of) in column_b:
[{'field1': 'value1'},{'field2','value2'}]

depending on emptiness of the fields, i am choosing one or another:
select
   coalesce(column_a::json, column_b) as res
from my_table

In case of column_a presence, it returns as json object and it is ok.
How to get the result as list of jsons? I would like to have:
[{'field0': 'value0'}]


There is no such thing as "JSON object", or "JSON array". JSON is text, that in various programming languages is handled by the type string. JSON is a text representation of a data structure (that can be an object or an array or something else, a number for example). In order to manipulate the encoded data, the JSON needs to be parsed. The result of parsing is a data structure similar to the one used to generate the JSON. The data that you show in the question is valid JavaScript, but not JSON.

I am parsing that data via python. in one case it is list of dict, in second - dict. It is better if i will receive list of dict all the time no matter how many objects in.

and btw, in the postgre that column is json type and not text (string) as you mentioned. that is different behaviour.

You can use the json_typeof function to distinguish whether a json value is an array or something else and then conditionally wrap it

@axiac "JSON object" and "JSON array" are perfectly valid terms in the context of SQL/JSON standard and its Postgres implementation. Here's MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server docs all acting like there is such a thing.

@Zegarek Probably axiac has in mind the single quotes that do make OP's examples invalid JSON.

@Stefanov.sm I'm just addressing the somewhat controversial opening statement saying there's no such thing, nothing else. I agree the "valid JavaScript, not JSON" part at the end is a good hint that if Postgres was to consume those as literals, it would consider them invalid. Although OP already clarified they're showing value examples from their app, in Python's notation, already mapped.

@Zegarek Fair enough, I cannot but agree.

Coalesce() doesn't necessarily fit here because array-wrapping a null produces a non-null, single-element array. If you resort to a case, it can do coalesce()'s job without its help:
demo at db<>fiddle
select case column_a is not null
       when true then json_build_array(column_a::json)
       else column_b
       end as res
from my_table;

To make the columns more lightweight, faster to read/write/process, support more functions and operators including JSONPath expressions, index and search more efficiently, switch to jsonb.
The price is small:

jsonb does not preserve white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not keep duplicate object keys. If duplicate keys are specified in the input, only the last value is kept.


Use jsonb_typeof().  It's not elegant, but it works:
create table my_table (column_a jsonb, column_b jsonb);
insert into my_table values 
  ('{"field0": "value0"}', '[{"field1": "value1"}, {"field2": "value2"}]'),
  (null, '[{"field1": "value1"}, {"field2": "value2"}]'),
  (null, null)
;

select case jsonb_typeof(coalesce(column_a, column_b))
         when 'array' then coalesce(column_a, column_b)
         else jsonb_build_array(coalesce(column_a, column_b))
       end as result
  from my_table;

Working fiddle

Since column_a should be text as OP says then column_a::jsonb in all expressions. Or a CTE?

I support considering the switch from json to jsonb but if you just switch all of a sudden to jsonb, it'll deform their values. json keeps whitespace, original key order and duplicate keys, all of which jsonb will get rid of, which OP or something downstream in their app might not expect.
